# Rename file from Day of the Year to YYMMDD0000

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, rename

I have a file with this name
ims2015255_4km_GIS_v1.3.png so it shows the 255 day of year 2015.

I want to auto rename this file to read like this

SNC_obs_YYMMDD0000.png The time to be always 0000

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the original name is fairly easy.

```
input=ims2015255_4km_GIS_v1.3.png
[[ $input =~ ims(....)(...)_ ]] && year=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} day=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Converting that into a new date might be trickier. If you have GNU `date`, though, you can use

```
output=$(date --date "$year-1-1 + $(($day - 1)) days" +"SNC_obs_%Y%m%d0000.png")
```

---

If you aren't using `bash` and are limited to POSIX-specified features, try the following to set `year` and `day`.

```
tmp=${input#ims}
tmp=${tmp%%_*}
year=${tmp%???}
day=${tmp#????}
```

Comment: copied what you wrote into a test.sh script, but it tells me error:
in.sh: 2: in.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: You don't appear to be executing the script with `bash`.

Comment: copied this into a .sh script still doesnt work : #!/bin/sh

input=ims2016001_4km_GIS_v1.3.png
[[ $input =~ ims(....)(...)_ ]] && year=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} day=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}


output=$(date --date "$year-1-1 + $(($day - 1)) days" +"SNC_obs_%Y%m%d0000.png")

#!/bin/bash

Comment: Without proof to the contrary, I can only assume that a script starting with `#!/bin/sh` is *not* run with `bash`.

Comment: And don't post code in a comment; it is nearly impossible to read.